# Conflict is using gcloud and google-api-client in ruby

Tags: google-api-ruby-client, gcloud-ruby

I want to install gcloud 0.11.0, which is depandent on google-api-client version 0.8.3. However, in order to user Google Drive, I need 0.9+.

How can they reside together? Google specifically says - you can use them both... Huh?!

> The Google APIs Ruby Client is a client library for using the broad set of Google APIs. gcloud is built specifically for the Google Cloud Platform and is the recommended way to integrate Google Cloud APIs into your Ruby applications. If your application requires both Google Cloud Platform and other Google APIs, the 2 libraries may be used by your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using them both? The namespaces are different, so I believe it should work just fine.

Also, the next version of gcloud-ruby (due out soon) should be on 0.9.x.

Comment: Yes. The namespaces are indeed different, however the loaded version is 0.8.3 and not 0.9.x, thus I dont have the drive api, etc

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I see. Well hopefully the next version of gcloud-ruby on Google API Client 0.9.x will solve your issue. You can monitor the status on this pull request: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby/pull/733.